# What is the last character when using Order By in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, special-characters

I've got a report where I need to enter the "from" and "to" characters for a field but I'm trying to get all the records.

If I enter " " (space) for the "from" and "福西" as the "to". Then this currently gets all the data because the last record is "福西" however I'm wanting to know what the very last possible character could be as it could change over time.

It would be fine if all my data was English and then I would just search "A" to "Z" but I need to capture all the special characters e.g. "福西".

If I type in SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') then I get Latin1_General_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://unicode-table.com/en/#cjk-unified-ideographs) webpage to get the last character which I think should work